# How to unit test a refresh functionality with stub objects

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm working on a unit test which executes some business logic that will eventually result in a refresh (so execute the same query again) of the data.

Using Dependency Injection (with Castle-Windsor) the unit tests use stub objects, so a static list of entities is returned from the method that gets the data.

So how can I test whether this method is called again?

I abused a date-time field in one of the entities to test the second get (DateTime after refresh != before refresh), but I don't think this is really a good solution.

Can someone offer me an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "So how can I test whether this method is called again?" sounds like you really want *mocks* rather than *stubs* - you're testing *protocol* rather than just having a static set of data to be returned. Personally I like the [Rhino.Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you please elaborate on how a mock object can help me with this problem? (I don't know anything about Rhino.Mocks)

Comment: Mocking tests your interaction with the dependency, rather than just setting values to be returned. See http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Introduction.ashx for an introduction to Rhino.Mocks - for general "what is mocking" questions I'd be doing a search for a good article to start with.

Comment: (i.e. I don't know any good articles offhand, so I'd be doing a search which you can do just as easily. Sorry not to have any appropriate resources off the top of my head.)